# EnhancedGrid get Selected cells

Tags: grid, selector, dojo

I'm working with EnhancedGrid and the selector plugin [like here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Selector.html) and I need to get every cell that is selected.
I was able to get the rows and columns like this:

```
var rows = grid.selection.getSelected('row', null);
var cols = grid.selection.getSelected('col', null);
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
var cells =  grid.selection.getSelected('cell', null);
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my solution:

```
func = function(type, startPoint, endPoint, selected){

    var cells = selected["cell"];
    var cols = selected["col"];
    var rows = selected["row"];
}

var handle =dojo.connect(grid, "onEndDeselect", func);
var handle = dojo.connect(grid, "onEndSelect", func);
```

Thankyou anyway